# how can I add this to PATH, after instalation pipenv? on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Linux

Tags: python, python-venv, pipenv, pipenv-install

after instalation pipenv, this alarm arose:

```
WARNING: The scripts pipenv and pipenv-resolver are installed in '/home/sina/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pipenv-2023.11.15 setuptools-69.0.2
```

This is my way to fix it:

For bash:
Open your ~/.bashrc file in a text editor.:

`nano ~/.bashrc`

At the end of the file:

`export PATH="$PATH:/home/sina/.local/bin"`

Save the file and exit.

restart your terminal or run the following command:

`source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how can I add this to PATH for using peprnv in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup suggests you installed `pipenv` via `pip install pipenv --user`.

As per [documentation](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-pipenv), you need indeed to modify one of the files loaded by the shell on startup. The documentation suggests updating `~/.profile`, not `~/.bashrc`.

Alternatively, if you can, you can install pipenv via your favourite package manager (as root); in that case, it'll be available in the `PATH`.